# Heap corruption error when deleting array

Tags: c++, mergesort, dynamic-arrays

I am attempting to read in a text file containing a list of random numbers and ordering them using mergesort to display. The numbers are read in to a dynamic array. Unfortunately, a heap corruption error is detected whenever I attempt to delete arrays that are not in use.

Mergesort Function:

```
void mergesort(int *arr, int first, int last)
{
if(first < last)
   {
   int middle = ((first + last)/2);
   mergesort(arr, first, middle);
   mergesort(arr, middle+1, last);
   merge(arr, first, last); 
   }
}
```

Error occurs in Merge Function when I delete tempArr:

```
void merge(int *arr, int first, int last)
{
int *tempArr = new int[last];

int mid = (first+last)/2;
int first1 = first;
int last1 = mid;
int first2 = mid + 1;
int last2 = last;

int index = first1;

for(; (first1 <= last1) && (first2 <= last2); ++index)
{
    if (arr[first1] < arr[first2])
    {
        tempArr[index] = arr[first1];
        ++first1;
    }
    else
    {
        tempArr[index] = arr[first2];
        ++first2;
    }
}

for(; first1 <= last1; ++first1, ++index)
    tempArr[index] = arr[first1];

for(; first2 <= last2; ++first2, ++index)
    tempArr[index] = arr[first2];

for(index=first;index<=last;++index)
    arr[index] = tempArr[index];

delete [] tempArr;
}
```

Comment: Besides the use of `new`, `delete` and the streams, I wouldn't call that C++. Use references instead of pointers to pass arguments "by reference", and use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of raw arrays.

Comment: As for your problem, run it in a debugger, and step through the code line by line while making sure you do not overwrite the end of the arrays.

Comment: Note that `(first+last)/2` can overflow - `first + (last - first)/2` is safer.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, it turns out that changing '(first+last)/2' to 'first + (last - first)/2' solved the heap corruption error. However, my output is not correct. Instead of '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10', I get '-33686019 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9' where the first value is corrupted.

Comment: You'll need to go through a debugger to solve this. The indexing is apparently off somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you allocate your array as `int *tempArr = new int[last]`. The number of its elements is `last` and their indices are `0`, `1`, ... `last - 1`.

Near the end of the function, you have this:

```
for(; first2 <= last2; ++first2, ++index)
    tempArr[index] = arr[first2];
```

`last2` is initialised to the value of `last`. This means the final assignment in the loop will be when `index == last`, so you're accessing `tempArr[last]`. That's out of array bounds.